# Why app update play console stuck in review?

Tags: android, google-play-console, review

my app stuck "in review" over two weeks. My app has an errors message but app show "In Review". How to contacts to play console for quick review because this is important update

I have try to fix but i don't know that error can influence own review Play Console.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "My app has an errors message"

can you share it?